Can the college restrict a student from entering washroom?
I study in an Indian college which is kind of liberal (you can skip classes, roam freely in the campus, exit and enter campus anytime, talk with people of opposite sex, etc.).
So there are different schools in my college (School of Technology, Pharmacy, Humanities, etc.). Each school is located in different blocks. Generally a student from any school can use the washroom which is located in a different school. So School of Tech student can use washroom which is in the block of School of Pharmacy. There's no rule which says that any student can use any washroom but it is de facto in some sense.
The college prioritises a specific school. Let's call it X. When a student tried to enter the washroom in school X, the security guard restricted the student from entering, saying that only students of school X can enter the washroom (they are following the orders of higher officials). Is this legal? Is this a human right violation?

I'll try to give some more context. The college is like a U-shaped building. It looks something like this:

Source: https://x.com/CCTV/status/933252547455860736
So, all the blocks of the college are interconnected and all the students can move from one block to another without any restriction.
All students can access washroom of any other block (which can belong to a different school). Only school X is restricting entry and not following the de facto.

Which human right do you suspect is being violated here?

@bdb484 Right to life of the Indian Constitution?

@RandomPerson are suggesting that people who are not allowed to use that particular washroom inevitably die?

Many stores and restaurants have "washrooms only for customers" rules. Why do you think schools should have any less right to restrict who can use their washrooms?

@RandomPerson How does the inability to access this specific bathroom affect anyone's right to life?

I think it is pretty clear that school X could well restrict access to their building without impacting human rights.

An acquaintance had some unfortunate health problems for some time and got a disability card that allowed him access to any publicly accessible toilet; he needed that. So restaurants, stores, and probably this college would have to allow him use of their toilets.

I'm still stuck on how this liberal institution allows you to talk to the opposite sex.

@TigerGuy To give you a better context, there are many colleges in India which actively prohibit students from talking to people of opposite sex.

@littleadv Right to life is a complex right in India. It involves human dignity. The manner in which a person is able to manage bodily functions of urination, defecation, and menstruation is at the core of human dignity. https://blog.ipleaders.in/article-21/

@bdb484 https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/248599

@JonCuster Isn't it discriminatory to not allow certain students to access washroom? It reminds me of the past racial segregation in the US.

@Barmar The college has superior authority than the school. Any student can access any school's washroom de facto. Why can school X put new restrictions?

Much discrimination is legal. You discriminate every day.

@RandomPerson In English, college is as type of school. I wasn't making a distinction between levels in the hierarchy of the university, just saying that colleges are like any other accomodation. They can decide who can use their facilities.

The owner of a building can restrict access to it
As long as they do not do so for an unlawful discriminatory reason (e.g. race, religion, etc.), it's their building and they can decide who can come in.

The college as a whole could be in trouble if some students cannot find a toilet anywhere, but sending every student to their own department would be legit.

Well I can classify it as discrimination based on the school of a student.

Discrimination is not in general illegal. Attending a different school within a college is not a “protected” characteristic (I.e. one for which discrimination would be illegal)

@RandomPerson yes, it’s discrimination, but it’s not unlawful discrimination. Choosing which students to admit and reject based on their academic ability is also discrimination.

@DaleM There's one thing which I forgot to mention. School X charges very high tuition fees than compared to other schools (almost twice or thrice compared to other schools). So, can we consider it as economic discrimination in some sense?

@RandomPerson Economic discrimination is not illegal. Luxury car dealers commit economic discrimination.

@Barmar I'm not sure what you're trying to mean, but I'll try to use your analogy. If the best lane of the road is reserved only for luxury cars, and the other bad lanes are meant for non-luxury cars, isn't that discrimination? Maybe it's not illegal, but it's definitely immoral and I hope people fight peacefully to end this discrimination :)

@RandomPerson It would be bad public policy, since it would cause excess congestion in the other lanes and they'd have to widen the road to accomodate that traffic. But immoral or illegal? No.

@RandomPerson haven’t you just described a toll road? They discriminate against poor people
